# How to switch between network interfaces from console?

Tags: virtualbox, networking, network-bridge, nat

I've installed Debian in my VirtualBox (my host OS is Ubuntu). And there I configured two network interfaces: eth0 as NAT, and eth1 as Bridge.

NAT I need to have access to the internet in virtual OS, but Bridge I need because I want this virtual OS to be a part of my local network.

How to switch from these network interfaces? For example now I use eth0 (NAT), but some time later I need to turn off eth0 and turn on eth1.

P.S. There is no Desktop Environment in guest OS (Debian), so I need to do this in terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With or without NetworkManager?

Comment: without networkManager. There is no desktop environment in guest OS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If both interface are configured in `/etc/network/interfaces` you can use

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

to bring eth0 up and

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

to take eth0 down

Comment: Otherwise `ifconfig eth0 up/down` works fine although I guess some prefer the `ip link set eth0 up/down` now.

Comment: I've tried this before asking a question, but it didn't work. But thank you for noticing that both interfaces should be configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`. The second one wasn't configured by default, so I've added a few lines in `/etc/network/interfaces` file and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I use

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && ifup eth1
sudo ifdown eth1 && ifup eth0
```

The 1st stops `eth0` and starts `eth1` and the second does it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

On a virtualbox running Ubuntu 16.04

`sudo ifdown eth0` didn't work
giving `Unknown interface eth0`

**I needed to do this instead:**

Turn off network:

`sudo ifconfig eth0 down`

Turn on network:

`sudo ifconfig eth0 up`

(In my case there was no `eth0` but there was `enp0s3` so I replaced that above.)